# GAE Datastore and Objectify: main and archive tables

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

We just moved from JDO to Objectify in our GAE Datastore processing.
Now we want to split one table (ok, one kind) into main and archive ones.
So we need two classes to represent the two kinds, the classes have the exact same instance variables (= entity properties).
The obvious solution for that is to have one base class with all the instance variables and two subclasses that will have the @Entity annotation.
The other solution is to have the archive class as the subclass of the main one.

Did anyone encounter such a problem and has expeirence to share?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 'archive' is to hold old data that is no longer live that you may need to look at later for historical or reporting reasons I would choose option 2, which is two classes with the same instance variables.

A few reasons:

- This allows you to migrate your active 'schema' and retain old data without needing to migrate existing archive records or worry about removed fields
- you can index different fields which allows you to manage datastore read/write costs more effectively
- you can add additional meta information (such as archive dates, expiration dates etc) which allow you to manage your archive with a different lifecycle. This may be important depending on how much data you end up archiving

Comment: I do not understand your answer.
First of all, in both my options, the two classes share instance variables, so I didn't see why you chose option 2.

Comment: continue from above:  <br/>
as for the list of reasons:  <br/>
* there are already optional properties in the active table.  Optional (or removed) properties are built-in in Datastore.  <br/>
* I can index different fields - that is correct. so which should be the base and which is the subclass?  <br/>
* I have additional properties for archiving operations.  However, there is a possibility of an entity to be "revived" (moved back from archive to main table), and it retains archiving properties.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood. I took option 2 to be option 3: Two classes which have the same contents, but are not coupled in a polymorphic sense.